# Code evaluation system with Nodejs (running student codes for programming courses)

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a project and it includes creating a code evaluation system for programming courses. I need to run user-submitted codes (written in JAVA) and return back the result (output) to the student. I'm planning to use NodeJS for the server but I don't know what to use for remote code execution, if you have ever done something like this please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Can't you just take the original java code, compile it and run it in a container or VM?

Comment: I'm confused about what to use for the container or vm. Is there any isolated vm that runs java code

Comment: You could use a generic VM like a KVM based which uses a prepared image in qcow2 format which you start with JDK installed within. Then you mount some folder with the source which you then compile and run and post the result onto some server (like the host). But using a container with Docker would probably be easier and achieve the same goal. You basically need a JDK container and then mount the user code into it and compile & execute while running. Katacoda has some nice introductions if you are unfamiliar with Docker.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think I can go with docker

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  in-built child process module of Node.js

Below is an example with bash.

You can adapt it to Java.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

 exec('cat *.js missing_file | wc -l', (error, stdout, stderr) =>
 { if (error) { 
console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
 return;
 } 
console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);

 console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`); }
);
```

Link: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Doesn't this approach harms the host system. Shouldn't I do this with container or isolated vm

Comment: What do you mean 'harm' the system? Are the students writing virus? Talking about vm, you can just put the whole process within the vm.

Comment: I mean their code should be isolated from the host system. They shouldn't use filesystem etc.